# How to add user for busybox su

Tags: rooting, superuser, busybox

I have successfully been able to copy busybox into system/bin/. I have also set busybox

```
chmod +g busybox
chmod +s busybox
chmod 4777 busybox
```

When I run busybox su it says user root not found. How do I add the user in android?. Maybe I will need to write some files in system/etc maybe?

Comment: busybox `su` is no valid applet on android (along with many others)

Comment: I was able to add a user with busybox useradd root but because android doesn't use /etc/passwd busybox su will not work